# How to find the last value depends on an event value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, lag

I have the date who likes :

| Key | DATE | Event_Date | Event | LastEventDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-01 | NULL |  |  |
| 1 | 2021-12-02 | NULL |  |  |
| 1 | 2021-12-03 | NULL |  |  |
| 1 | 2021-12-04 | NULL |  |  |
| 1 | 2021-12-05 | NULL |  |  |
| 1 | 2021-12-06 | 2021-12-06 | Yes | 2021-12-06 |
| 1 | 2021-12-07 | NULL |  | 2021-12-06 |
| 1 | 2021-12-08 | NULL |  | 2021-12-06 |
| 1 | 2021-12-09 | 2021-12-09 | Yes | 2021-12-09 |
| 1 | 2021-12-10 | NULL |  | 2021-12-09 |
| 1 | 2021-12-11 | NULL |  | 2021-12-09 |
| 1 | 2021-12-12 | NULL |  | 2021-12-09 |
| 1 | 2021-12-13 | 2021-12-13 | Yes | 2021-12-13 |

The challenge s to create the red column : LastEventDate.

I tried this

```
SELECT
  Key,
  Event_Date,
  value_partition,
  first_value(Event_Date) over (partition by value_partition order by Key)
FROM (
  SELECT
    Key,
    Event_Date,
    sum(case when Event_Date is null then 0 else 1 end) over (order by Key) as value_partition
    FROM MyTable
  ORDER BY Key ASC
) as A
```

But I got the error:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Does anyone has idea how to get the LastEventDate column?

Comment: Delete `ORDER BY Key ASC`???

Comment: When deleting the der by the script doen't do want  want :

Comment: Please post data as text not images.

Comment: `max(event_date) over(partition by key_ order by date)`

Comment: I've tried to post it as a text but it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you  very much  Iptr. The script is working.

Answer (score 1):

An `ORDER BY` is only allowed in a subquery when there's a `TOP` or `OFFSET FETCH`.

The `ORDER BY` in the window functions should be on the `DATE` column.

> ```
> WITH CTE_DATA AS (
>   SELECT [Key], [DATE], Event_Date, Event
>   , SUM(IIF(Event_Date IS NOT NULL,1,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY [Key] ORDER BY [DATE]) AS Rnk
>   FROM MyTable
> )
> SELECT [Key], [DATE], Event_Date, Event
> , FIRST_VALUE(Event_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY [Key], Rnk ORDER BY [DATE]) AS LastEventDate
> FROM CTE_DATA
> ORDER BY [Key], [DATE];
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Key | DATE       | Event_Date | Event | LastEventDate
> --: | :--------- | :--------- | :---- | :------------
>   1 | 2021-12-01 | null       | null  | null         
>   1 | 2021-12-02 | null       | null  | null         
>   1 | 2021-12-03 | null       | null  | null         
>   1 | 2021-12-04 | null       | null  | null         
>   1 | 2021-12-05 | null       | null  | null         
>   1 | 2021-12-06 | 2021-12-06 | Yes   | 2021-12-06   
>   1 | 2021-12-07 | null       | null  | 2021-12-06   
>   1 | 2021-12-08 | null       | null  | 2021-12-06   
>   1 | 2021-12-09 | 2021-12-09 | Yes   | 2021-12-09   
>   1 | 2021-12-10 | null       | null  | 2021-12-09   
>   1 | 2021-12-11 | null       | null  | 2021-12-09   
>   1 | 2021-12-12 | null       | null  | 2021-12-09   
>   1 | 2021-12-13 | 2021-12-13 | Yes   | 2021-12-13
> ```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=855332b62cbd5b3319962424316e69a0)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use a running windowed `MAX` for this

```sql
SELECT
  t.[Key],
  t.DATE,
  t.Event_Date,
  t.Event,
  LastEventDate = MAX(t.Event_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY t.[Key] ORDER BY t.Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM MyTable t
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=088cbea162e783a9b2e15e170dad57e8)